# Fail- ICI_INVALID_HANDLE(0)

Tags: geneos

I see this error in my Geneos active console quite often whenever we use "SQL Toolkit" plugin, This error gets corrected whenever we restart the probe but reappears again. There is no pattern by which these error shows up.

Has anybody come across such error in Geneos and does anyone have nay solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an Oracle related error. Check that you can execute the SQL statement on command line from the server that the netprobe is running on using the account that the netprobe is running under.

Supplementary checks would be around the Environment variables like ORACLE_HOME etc.

Might be beneficial to see what SQL you are running and tagging this with ORACLE and SQL